# Getting Data from PHP, JSON Highcharts?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, highcharts

Hi I am trying to get data from **`MySql`** table and show the data in **`Highcharts`** by using **`PHP`** and **`Json`**
I have try the example from internet and it is working fine but when I try to get data from my file it show nothing.

**What I am trying to do:**
I am creating table of *office attendance system* and trying to show record day by day. So at **y axis** I want to count **names** of employees and **x axis** the **date** of attendance.

**Problem:** Nothing Is show from mu json.

Here is what my **`Json`** looks like:

```
[["Hamza","07\/04\/2014"],
["Junaid","07\/04\/2014"],
["Usman","07\/04\/2014"],
["Rajab","07\/04\/2014"],
["Hamza","08\/04\/2014"],
["Junaid","08\/04\/2014"],
["Usman","08\/04\/2014"],
["Rajab","08\/04\/2014"]]
```

I am having to value names and dates.

My **`PHP`** which is creating my **`Json`** code:

```
// Set the JSON header
header("Content-type: text/json");

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM attendence");
$a=array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 $row['name'] . "\t" . $row['date']. "\n";
 $b=array();
 array_push($b,$row['name']);
 array_push($b,$row['date']);
array_push($a,$b);
}
echo json_encode($a);
```

and this is my Jquery code:

```
$(function() {

    $.getJSON('highchart.php', function(data) {
        // Create the chart     
        $('#chart').highcharts('StockChart', {


            rangeSelector : {
                selected : 1,
                inputEnabled: $('#chart').width() > 480
            },

            title : {
                text : 'Attendence'
            },

            series : [{
                name : 'Empolyees',
                data : data,
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }]
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Your data doesn't make any sense.  You have a name and a date, but no numeric y-value.  Are you trying to show the count of those there on a particular day?  Or how many days an individual was there in some time period?

Comment: this is a attendance table and everyday many employees have to add there time in and time out so in a single day there are many entries of a single day in my json code I only show one day attendance but there are many days in my table with same day.

Comment: you didn't answer my question.  What **value** do you want your y axis to show?

Comment: sorry for late answer I want to count name and show it at y axis.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In the json_encode() you need to use JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK flag to avoid use string in your JSON
2. In the highstock you need to have timestamps and value, not name and date.
3. Dates should be timestamp, and as first element in array, not second as you have.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a count of all people on a given day, you need to write a SQL query that returns that information.  Assuming that `date` field is a `datetime` type and `name` is of `varchar` type:

```
SELECT COUNT(name) FROM attendence GROUP BY DATE(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you need to define what kind of data your x-axis will have
take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series/data-array-of-arrays-datetime/) (taken from highcharts website)

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },

        series: [{
            data: [
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1), 29.9], 
                [Date.UTC(2010, 2, 1), 71.5], 
                [Date.UTC(2010, 3, 1), 106.4]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: but i want to keep dates dynamic? any idea for that?

Comment: @Hamza i don't think this is a prolem. Just look how x-axis is defined as datetime. Also, in this example the data are [date,string]. I have no familiarity with highcharts, but i thought the above example did exactly what you  wanted